<ion-grid -> <ion-row - set conditionally background color
I use this code in order to set the background-color:
<ion-grid style="margin-left:2px;margin-right:2px;margin-top:5px;">
  <ion-row *ngFor="let scheduleRecordDayCompendium of scheduleRecordDayCompendiums; let i = index" 
       [style.color]="getLineColor(scheduleRecordDayCompendium)">
     <ion-col>

This is the getLineColor function:
getLineColor(scheduleRecordDayCompendium) {
  switch(scheduleRecordDayCompendium.day) {
  case 'SATURDAY':
    return '#00f';
  case 'SUNDAY':
    return '#f00';
 }
return '#000';

}
with [style.color] it works fine but how can I make it work with [style.backgound-color]?

Add [style.background-color]=<background color> to the <ion-row> element not working?

yes, this is not working

That's odd. My demo cannot reproduce your issue. In your <ion-col>element, do you set any background-color in CSS? Make sure you are not set the CSS rule, it could be overwrite the CSS rule from the <ion-row>

you can also try:
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': getLineColor(scheduleRecordDayCompendium)}"
